# How to graph multiple trending lines from mutilpe rrd files?

Tags: rrdtool

I have 3 separate rrd files each with cpu average data. I can graph each individually without issue. cpu average line and trending line (using LSLSLOPE)

I have been asked to combine all three into one graph. so I took my DEF, CEF, and VDEFs and made them with a, b, and c. I must have done something wrong because i am getting the following errors

```
     ./graph3avg.sh: line 42: VDEF:avg_a=a,AVERAGE: command not found
    ./graph3avg.sh: line 59: LINE2:avg_a#f0610f:App CPU Avg:dashes=5: command not found
```

I was not sure if its a command ordering thing with rrdtool or if i am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Thanks for your time!

here is the rrd command from the shell script

```
    graphname="Server $1 trending"
  rrdtool graph $ofile \
  --imgformat=PNG \
--alt-autoscale-max \
  --start=$starttime \
  --end=$endtime \
  --title="$graphname" \
  --font TITLE:12: \
  --units-exponent=2 \
  --color CANVAS#ececec \
  --vertical-label="CPU %" \
  --height=400 \
  --width=1000 \
   DEF:a="$ifile":cpu:AVERAGE:step=3600 \
   DEF:b="$ifile2":cpu:AVERAGE:step=3600 \
   DEF:c="$ifile3":cpu:AVERAGE:step=3600 \
   VDEF:avg_a=a,AVERAGE \
   VDEF:avg_b=b,AVERAGE \
   VDEF:avg_c=c,AVERAGE \
   VDEF:slope_a=a,LSLSLOPE \
   VDEF:slope_b=b,LSLSLOPE \
   VDEF:slope_c=c,LSLSLOPE \
   VDEF:cons_a=a,LSLINT \
   VDEF:cons_b=b,LSLINT \
   VDEF:cons_c=c,LSLINT \
   CDEF:lsl2_a=a,POP,slope_a,COUNT,*,cons_a,+ \
   CDEF:lsl2_b=b,POP,slope_b,COUNT,*,cons_b,+ \
   CDEF:lsl2_c=c,POP,slope_c,COUNT,*,cons_c,+ \
   LINE2:avg_a#f0610f:"App CPU Avg":dashes=5 \
   LINE3:lsl2_a#bd8a6c:"App CPU Trend\n" \
   LINE2:avg_b#0ff061:"Web CPU Avg":dashes=5 \
   LINE3:lsl2_b#48a068:"Web CPU Trend\n" \
   LINE2:avg_c#1fbcd8:"DB CPU Avg":dashes=5 \
   LINE3:lsl2_c#619da7:"App CPU Trend\n" \
   COMMENT:"\s" \
   COMMENT:"Start Date $startdate " \
   COMMENT:"End Date $enddate " \
   COMMENT:"\n" \
   COMMENT:"\n" \
   COMMENT:"Graph created on $today"
```

Comment: ok well this one can be marked closed. there was an extraneous char in the file. once that was removed, everything worked as expected.

i guess this entire thing should be deleted. Not sure what the process is in the case of the problem being a corrupted file.  MODs let me know or feel free to delete